# I want to be an exit node

Tags: exit-relays

First of all, forgive me for my bad English. I don't speak the language fluently. But I hope you can understand.

Into my torrc file, I added the following lines:

```
ExitPolicy accept *:20-21     # FTP
ExitPolicy accept *:22        # SSH
ExitPolicy accept *:23        # Telnet
ExitPolicy accept *:43        # WHOIS
ExitPolicy accept *:53        # DNS
ExitPolicy accept *:79        # finger
ExitPolicy accept *:80-81     # HTTP
ExitPolicy accept *:88        # kerberos
ExitPolicy accept *:110       # POP3
ExitPolicy accept *:143       # IMAP
ExitPolicy accept *:194       # IRC
ExitPolicy accept *:220       # IMAP3
ExitPolicy accept *:389       # LDAP
ExitPolicy accept *:443       # HTTPS
ExitPolicy accept *:464       # kpasswd
ExitPolicy accept *:465       # URD for SSM (more often: an alternative SUBMISSION port, see 587)
ExitPolicy accept *:531       # IRC/AIM
ExitPolicy accept *:543-544   # Kerberos
ExitPolicy accept *:554       # RTSP
ExitPolicy accept *:563       # NNTP over SSL
ExitPolicy accept *:587       # SUBMISSION (authenticated clients [MUA's like Thunderbird] send mail over STARTTLS SMTP here)
ExitPolicy accept *:636       # LDAP over SSL
ExitPolicy accept *:706       # SILC
ExitPolicy accept *:749       # kerberos 
ExitPolicy accept *:873       # rsync
ExitPolicy accept *:902-904   # VMware
ExitPolicy accept *:981       # Remote HTTPS management for firewall
ExitPolicy accept *:989-990   # FTP over SSL
ExitPolicy accept *:991       # Netnews Administration System
ExitPolicy accept *:992       # TELNETS
ExitPolicy accept *:993       # IMAP over SSL
ExitPolicy accept *:994       # IRCS
ExitPolicy accept *:995       # POP3 over SSL
ExitPolicy accept *:1194      # OpenVPN
ExitPolicy accept *:1220      # QT Server Admin
ExitPolicy accept *:1293      # PKT-KRB-IPSec
ExitPolicy accept *:1500      # VLSI License Manager
ExitPolicy accept *:1533      # Sametime
ExitPolicy accept *:1677      # GroupWise
ExitPolicy accept *:1723      # PPTP
ExitPolicy accept *:1755      # RTSP
ExitPolicy accept *:1863      # MSNP
ExitPolicy accept *:2082      # Infowave Mobility Server
ExitPolicy accept *:2083      # Secure Radius Service (radsec)
ExitPolicy accept *:2086-2087 # GNUnet, ELI
ExitPolicy accept *:2095-2096 # NBX
ExitPolicy accept *:2102-2104 # Zephyr
ExitPolicy accept *:3128      # SQUID
ExitPolicy accept *:3389      # MS WBT
ExitPolicy accept *:3690      # SVN
ExitPolicy accept *:4321      # RWHOIS
ExitPolicy accept *:4643      # Virtuozzo
ExitPolicy accept *:5050      # MMCC
ExitPolicy accept *:5190      # ICQ
ExitPolicy accept *:5222-5223 # XMPP, XMPP over SSL
ExitPolicy accept *:5228      # Android Market
ExitPolicy accept *:5900      # VNC
ExitPolicy accept *:6660-6669 # IRC
ExitPolicy accept *:6679      # IRC SSL  
ExitPolicy accept *:6697      # IRC SSL  
ExitPolicy accept *:8000      # iRDMI
ExitPolicy accept *:8008      # HTTP alternate
ExitPolicy accept *:8074      # Gadu-Gadu
ExitPolicy accept *:8080      # HTTP Proxies
ExitPolicy accept *:8082      # HTTPS Electrum Bitcoin port
ExitPolicy accept *:8087-8088 # Simplify Media SPP Protocol, Radan HTTP
ExitPolicy accept *:8232-8233 # Zcash
ExitPolicy accept *:8332-8333 # Bitcoin
ExitPolicy accept *:8443      # PCsync HTTPS
ExitPolicy accept *:8888      # HTTP Proxies, NewsEDGE
ExitPolicy accept *:9418      # git
ExitPolicy accept *:9999      # distinct
ExitPolicy accept *:10000     # Network Data Management Protocol
ExitPolicy accept *:11371     # OpenPGP hkp (http keyserver protocol)
ExitPolicy accept *:19294     # Google Voice TCP
ExitPolicy accept *:19638     # Ensim control panel
ExitPolicy accept *:50002     # Electrum Bitcoin SSL
ExitPolicy accept *:64738     # Mumble
ExitPolicy reject *:*
```

With this configuration am I really acting as an exit node? I have a 50 MB download and 30 MB of upload.
I want the Tor network to make full use of my connection. I don't want to limit anything for the other Tor users.

Is my configuration is correct?

Thank you all!

Comment: I voted up this question because Tor needs all the exit nodes it can get. In my view, anyone who is asking how they can do it better deserves an up-vote! And the question will result in answers that improve the likelihood of a functioning node.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it should be fine - don't forget to add ORPort and DirPort and make them reachable from the outer world also. And I have some TCP ports suggestions to open also, they are:

- IRC used to utilize also ports 7000-7010. I have seen it on DALNet and others
- XMPP is a very common thing today, so open 5222,5223,5269,5298,8010 - they are all important for it, not 5222 and 5223 as it is in your config
- Socks long-known port 1080 is quite a common one

UPDATE: additional torrc lines

```
ExitPolicy accept *:1080
ExitPolicy accept *:7000-7010
ExitPolicy accept *:5269
ExitPolicy accept *:5298
ExitPolicy accept *:8010
ORPort 443
DirPort 80
ClientOnly 0
```

Comment: Thank you for giving attention to my question!

You can explain to me how I can include ORPort and DirPort lines?

I'm not very good at handling this type of configuration.

Thank you all so much!

I want all users of Tor can use my connection as an exit node without imposing any restrictions.

Comment: Just add lines `ORPort <port>` and same for DirPort. The ip address is the one you're binding Tor to. If you have an external Internet address right on the machine, then it should be OK. But if you're behind the nat, i.e. you have a home router that receives the IP and internet from your ISP and your tor node is on a LAN-connected machine, use a static LAN address and put `<LAN ip>:<port>` instead of just port number to both directives and route TCP ports on your router to that LAN machine. `ClientOnly 0` is good as well - just to have it in config. Feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks again for your attention to my question.

Could you post an example of how I may be adding these lines in my torrc file?

I get my IP from my ISP.

Comment: do you have your PC/server hosting Tor plugged to your ISP directly or your ISP link is going to your home router and the tor host is behind that router?

Comment: My PC connects in Tor directly by my ISP.

My connection had 50Mbps for download. I did an upgrade! Now sane 70Mbps to download.

My connection is optical fiber.

I want to make all my bandwidth for users of the Tor network. Thus I believe that I will be contributing actively to help people from oppressive Governments worldwide.

I'm a big fan of the principles of the Tor.

Thanks again! And once again I apologize for my bad English.

Comment: My torrec file is like this: # This file was generated by Tor; if you edit it, comments will not be preserved
# The old torrc file was renamed to torrc.orig.1 or similar, and Tor will ignore it

DataDirectory C:\Users\Tiago\Documents\Outros Apps\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
GeoIPFile C:\Users\Tiago\Documents\Outros Apps\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\Tiago\Documents\Outros Apps\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6
HiddenServiceStatistics

Comment: It seems that you're using Tor Browser bundle, right? if so - install an expert bundle of Tor and make a different torrc for this. Put your ExitPolicy lines in the head, copy and paste mine addition in the answer after them and - make a different **non-privileged**/regular user for tor and add **as the very last line** `User username`. Feel free to ask further questions, I can make you a video tutorial if you want btw

Comment: Also check out this document for keeping a good exit relay going: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorExitGuidelines

Comment: @RogerDingledine a good doc except the counter-productive and bad advice about a website on port 80 - sadly, to combat too restrictive firewalls you need both 80 and 443 ports. In simple case 443 is used as ORPort, in complex case it's used as obfs3 or obfs4 pluggable transport port and additional port like 8080 is used as ORPort. ReverseDNS with 'proxy'-like name in it is questionable also - it will help the host to get banned, especially if it's a bridge. Disk encryption is also a question : I suggest using a tmpfs copy fired-up at boot, so reset is wipes it out clean to prevent leaks

Comment: Hi Alexey Vesnin.

I would be very grateful for tutoring on video.

Comment: Hello Roger Dingledine.

Thank you very much for help too.

I use disk encryption for years.

I'm using PGP Whole Disk Encryption.

Comment: Roger Dingledine, reading the link you sent was of great help.

Thank you!